# Make an iframe heigher

Tags: html, iframe, division

I am not able to cope with the iframe. I am trying to insert my curriculum in it, but although the width seems easily managable, the height does not repond to increments in the feature. The result is an iframe that ocupies the width of the page but is wide too narrwo to confortably scroll down. Downhere I leave the code (The issue is halfway) and my webpage, https://rubencioak.github.io/cv2.html, in case it's of any help.

```
<body>
        <!-- Wrapper -->
        <div id="wrapper">
            <!-- Main -->
            <div id="main">
                <div class="inner">
                    <!-- Header -->
                    <!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
                    <noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-TWMMZHX"
                    height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
                    <!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->

                    <header id="header">
                        <a href="https://rubencioak.github.io/" class="logo"> rubencioak.github.io  </a>
                        <ul class="icons">

                        <li><a href="mailto:rubenprzsnz@gmail.com" class="icon fa-envelope"><span class="label">Email</span></a></li>  
                        </ul>
                    </header>
                    
                    <!-- Content -->
                    <section>
                        <header class="main">
                            <h1>Curriculum Vitae</h1>
                        </header>

                        <!-- About Container -->
                        <div class="w3-container">
                            <div class="w3-content w3-text-color2 w3-padding-64" style="max-width:700px">
                                <p>
                                    <span>&nbsp;</span> Download [<a href="documents/Academic_CV___Ruben.pdf">pdf</a>]
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="Iframe-Liason-Sheet" class="iframe-border center-block-horiz">
                            <div class="responsive-wrapper responsive-wrapper-wxh-550x2000 w3-text-color2">
                                <p> <iframe width="75%" height="500%" src="https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=https://rubencioak.github.io/documents/Academic_CV___Ruben.pdf&embedded=true">
                                <p>Your web browser does not support iframes. Please click at the pdf link above. </p> </iframe> </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <section>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Sidebar -->
            <div id="sidebar">
                <div class="inner">

                    <!-- Menu -->
                    <nav id="menu">
                        <header class="major">
                            <h2>Menu</h2>
                        </header>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="index.html">Homepage</a></li>
                            <li><a href="research.html">Research</a></li>
                            <li><a href="cv.html">Curriculum</a></li>
                            <li><a href="teaching.html">Teaching</a></li>
                            <li><a href="contacts.html">Contacts</a></li>
                            <li><a href="referees.html">Referees</a></li>
                            <!--<li>
                                <span class="opener">Submenu</span>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Lorem Dolor</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Ipsum Adipiscing</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Tempus Magna</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Feugiat Veroeros</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li> -->
                        </ul>
                    </nav>

                    <section>
                        <header class="major">
                            <h2>Contact</h2>
                        </header>
                        <p>Please, contact me with any question, specially those regarding my reseach. Your feedback will be much apreciated</p>
                        <ul class="contact">
                            <li class="icon solid fa-envelope"><a href="rubenprzsnz@gmail.com">rubenprzsnz@gmail.com</a></li>
                            <!-- <li class="icon solid fa-phone">(000) 000-0000</li> -->
                            <li class="icon solid fa-building">
                            Departament d'Economia<br />
                            Edifici B<br />
                            Universitat Autònoma de Barcelona<br />
                            08193 Bellaterra, Barcelona, Spain</li>
                        </ul>
                    </section>

                    <!-- Footer -->
                    <footer id="footer">
                        <p class="copyright">&copy; Untitled. All rights reserved. Demo Images: <a href="https://unsplash.com">Unsplash</a>. Design: <a href="https://html5up.net">HTML5 UP</a>.</p>
                    </footer>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Scripts -->
            <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="assets/js/browser.min.js"></script>
            <script src="assets/js/breakpoints.min.js"></script>
            <script src="assets/js/util.js"></script>
            <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>

    </body>
```

Comment: What height to you want it to be? Can it be any height in pixels or a percentage of the viewport?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your height in your inline style on your iframe to vh (viewport height)instead of %. I changed the height to 1000vh using Dev Tools and it nearly filled the whole screen. That's not the ideal fix, but it works.

```
<iframe width="75%" height="500%" src="https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=https://rubencioak.github.io/documents/Academic_CV___Ruben.pdf&embedded=true">

<!------Change height to vh------>

<iframe width="75%" height="500vh" src="https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=https://rubencioak.github.io/documents/Academic_CV___Ruben.pdf&embedded=true">
```

Comment: I don't know if it's an ideal fix, but it worked perfectly and that's all what I need. Thanks!!!